# How to configure Squid Proxy behind Cloudflare Tunnel?

Tags: networking, squid, cloudflare

I am trying to use Squid Proxy behind Cloudflare Tunnel.

I just install Squid on my Rapberry PI with Ubuntu.
I just take a free Domain from Freenom and put it on Cloudflare. I add on Freenom the CF Nameservers.

On CF I add a new Tunnel on CF and bind it with my Raspberry PI. The tunnel does work fine.
Than I add new Application under the Tunnel with with a subdomain like: proxy.mydomein.tk, HTTP protocol, 127.0.0.1:3128

curl -x http://[proxy.mydomain.tk]:3128 http://[targetdomain].com -v

If I curl

curl -x http://127.0.01:3128 http://[targetdomain].com -v

from the local (Raspberry PI) it does work fine.
I can’t receive a response from the server using the tunnel from out beide the local network.

I have tried with TCP and HTTP

Anyone can help with the correct configuration?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Use Squid as a normal proxy? If so: you probably can't. CF probably expects to talk to a HTTP server, not a proxy server.

Comment: I want use the Proxy to submit CURL request through my local network from remote server (outside of my network)

Comment: You should probably include some information on how things is configured, because as your question stands I have no idea how stuff is configured, what products you're  using or what error messages you're getting. But remember that forward proxy is *not* HTTP.